# Javascript select all button in php

Tags: php, javascript

Hi All  First of all I don't know Javascript, I got this script from the internet but can't get it to work.  If someone can please be so kind and assist me.  I'm trying to create a "check all" & "uncheck all" button on my form for my checkboxes, if I click the button it does not select anything.  Where am I going wrong?

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<head>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--

<!-- Begin
function CheckAll(chk)
{
for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
chk[i].checked = true ;
}

function UnCheckAll(chk)
{
for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
chk[i].checked = false ;
}
// End -->
</script>
</head>
```

And then the form:

```
$sql0 = "SELECT * FROM .....
$result0 = mysql_query($sql0);
echo "<form name='myform' action='...' method='post'>";
while($row0 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result0)) {
   $test_id=$row0['id'];
   $test_name=$row0['test_name'];

echo "  <table width=600px>";
echo "      <tr>";
echo "          <td width=30px><input name='question[$test_id][]' type='checkbox' value='1' /></td>";
echo "          <td width=580px align=left>$test_name</td>";
echo "      </tr>";
echo "  </table>";
}
echo "</P>";
echo "<input type='button' name='Check_All' value='Check All' onClick='CheckAll(document.myform.check_list)'>";
echo "<input type='button' name='Un_CheckAll' value='Uncheck All' onClick='UnCheckAll(document.myform.check_list)'>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: you have passed check_list as checkbox name. and in input tag, it is coming dynamically ... check it .. and reply so that i can move ahead with the code ..

Comment: Hi, Yes I see what you mean, if I change the input tag to check_list it works but I need to get the information from the table so that I can use it on my action form, what to do now?

Comment: Show the rendered html (go to your web-page, and 'view source', post the relevant html from there), as the PHP is irrelevant to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd highly recommend using jQuery, it allows you to focus on the logic and not worry about cross browser issues you might run into.

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   //check all
   $('input[name="Check_All"]').click(function () {
      //for all checkboxes where the name begins with "question", check them
      $('input[name^="question"]').attr('checked', true);
   });

   //uncheck all
   $('input[name="Un_CheckAll"]').click(function () {
      //for all checkboxes where the name begins with "question", uncheck them
      $('input[name^="question"]').attr('checked', false);
   });
});
</script>
```

Here's the breakdown...

Select all buttons on the page where the `name` attribute is set to `Check_all`

```
$('input[name="Check_All"]')
```

When the found item(s) are clicked, execute the code in the function that is passed

```
$('input[name="Check_All"]').click(function () {
    //javascript code here
});
```

for all checkboxes where the name begins with "question", check them

```
$('input[name^="question"]').attr('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you don't know javascript, i'd strongly recommend you investigate jquery - a library which eliminates cross browser issues and makes a huge amount of javascript far easier.

simply include this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and your code

```
<input type='button' name='Check_All' value='Check All' onClick='$(":checkbox").attr("checked",true);'>
```

untested, but should be okay.

Comment: I think your last code will always set the checkbox as checked, making it impossible to uncheck? Anyways, why do you need that js?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<td width=30px><input name='question[$test_id][]' type='checkbox' value='1' /></td>";
```

to this:

```
<td width=30px><input name='check_list[]' type='checkbox' value='1' /></td>";
```

Comment: No unfortunately its not solving the problem.